# vba code works in 2010 ad doesn't work in 2007

Tags: excel, vba

This line works normally in excel 2010, and doesn't work in excel 2007 - on another comp.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets...
```

Compile Error: Can't find property or library
"ws" is marked in yellow

What could be the reason, pls ?

Comment: Did you type in the code that declares `ws`? If not, can you delete the line `dim ws as Worksheet` and type it in again?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I did not declare ws. There is no need to declare ws. The same wba laguage is on 2007 and 2010 version.

Comment: @Alegro You didn't declare it? You on purpose enjoy no IntelliSense support?

Comment: @Alegro: In that case, please make sure that you have `option explicit` as the 1st line in your code file. Post that, type in `dim ws as Worksheet` in the method (where you are getting the error). Always do a Debug -> Compile to make sure that your code uses variables that are declared first.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, I will try. It seems never ending to learn. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason could be any missing reference in `Tools -> References` (indicated by `MISSING:` in front of it).

Fix any missing references, and it will be gone.

Comment: I just wanted to re-emphasize this answer. In Office 2010 if you use functionality of a different Office program in your VBA, and use early-binding you will have added a reference to the 2010 version. Unfortunately, this is not backwards compatiable as people without Office 2010 lack the references. If you want to use a different Office program and keep backwards compatibility, you need to use late-binding.

Comment: @DanielCook, ThankYou. Very usefull info. Let's say - Solved.