# ms 365 Excel VBA Workbook has missing VBA References

Tags: excel, vba

I developed a ms365 Excel application on an iMac. Got running and then transferred file to PC running Windows 10. The Macros execute OK. Some of the VBA sub run OK. When I execute a specific sub with `" **Format(Now, yyyymmddhhmm)**"` I get the error

> "Visual for Basic Applications - Compile error - Can't find Project or Library".

Going to Tools/References show available and missing references. An example of missing reference is "vbapprect type library".  Is there a way to download these missing references and then where to place them?

Some of the Workbook VBA Subs give an error that show missing references. Example is Missing vbapprect type library

Comment: Only you know what references apart from the defaults you have selected, so only you know how to "download" them.

Answer (score -1):

The **Format** needs some double quotes on the second argument, like this

```
Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmm")
```

Comment: While it is so, this would not cause the "Can't find Project or Library" error.

Comment: It worked or not?  May be is something else. Did you try running step by step using F8  in VBE? I just tested this Dim s$: s = Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmm") and it works.

Comment: Try getting yourself some [`MISSING:` items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110487/11683) in the references first.

Comment: The Format, has nothing to do with the missing items. May be this url may help you http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx. If you can post an image of the references you are using.

Comment: When you have a missing item in the references, random pieces of the code will stop working. Most often the members of the `Strings` module in VBA, which `Format` is.

Comment: Just correct the missing reference and your problem may be solved.

Comment: That is what is being asked in the question. How to correct the missing reference. Have you read it?

Comment: @GSerg, I've ben trying to help you! I' posted a url that might help you and I also told you to post the image of the references you are using. You didn't comment the url and you didn´t post any image!!!

Comment: Apart from not reading the question, you have also failed to recognize that I am not the OP.

Comment: @Gserg, sorry for the misunderstood.